# How to write the "prints" of python into a txt file?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a web page using selenium and Pycharm, so far this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
mozilla_path = r"C:\Users\ivrav\Python38\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.bundesbank.de/en/bundesbank/research/research-centre/people/people-738992")
time.sleep(3)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="top"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li/div/a""").click()
Researcher=driver.find_element_by_class_name("main")
print(Researcher.text)
```

The prints are the following:

```
Emanuel Mönch
Head of Research
27.06.2019
Research Interests
Risk Premium Modeling
Financial Intermediation, Asset Prices, and Macroeconomic Dynamics
Asset Price Anomalies
Business Cycle Analysis and Macroeconomic Forecasting
Modeling Macroeconomic Expectations
Refereed Publications
Ghysels, E., C. Horan and E. Moench (2018), Forecasting through the Rear-view Mirror: Data Revisions and Bond Return Predictability, Review of Financial Studies, Vol. 31(2), pp. 678-714.
Abrahams, M., T. Adrian, R. K. Crump, E. Moench and R. Yu (2016), Decomposing Real and Nominal Yield Curves, Journal of Monetary Economics, Vol. 84, pp. 182-200.
Andrade, P., R. K. Crump, S. Eusepi and E. Moench (2016), Fundamental Disagreement, Journal of Monetary Economics, Vol. 83, pp. 106-128.
Liu, W. and E. Moench (2016), What Predicts U.S. Recessions, International Journal of Forecasting, Vol. 32(4), pp. 1138–1150.
Adrian, T., R. K. Crump and E. Moench (2015), Regression-Based Estimation of Dynamic Asset Pricing Models, Journal of Financial Economics, Vol. 118 (2), pp. 211–244.
Lucca, D. and E. Moench (2015), The Pre-FOMC Announcement Drift, Journal of Finance, Vol. 70(1), pp. 329-371, winner of the Amundi Smith Breeden First Prize for the best capital markets paper published in the Journal of Finance in 2015.
Adrian, T., R. K. Crump and E. Moench (2013), Pricing the Term Structure with Linear Regressions, Journal of Financial Economics, Vol. 110(1), pp. 110-138.
Moench, E., S. Ng, and S. Potter (2013), Dynamic Hierarchical Factor Models, Review of Economics and Statistics, Vol. 95(5), pp. 1811-1817.
Moench, E. (2012), Term Structure Surprises: The Predictive Content of Curvature, Level, and Slope, Journal of Applied Econometrics, Vol. 27(4), pp. 574-602.
Carvalho, C., N. Klagge, and E. Moench (2011), The Persistent Effects of a False News Shock, Journal of Empirical Finance, Vol 18(4), pp. 597-615.
Moench, E. and S. Ng (2011), A Hierarchical Factor Analysis of US Housing Market Dynamics, The Econometrics Journal, Vol. 14(1), pp. C1-C24.
Adrian, T., E. Moench, H.S. Shin (2010), Macro Risk Premium, and Intermediary Balance Sheet Quantities, IMF Economic Review, Vol 58(1), pp. 179-207.
Aragon, D., E. Moench, and J. Vickery (2010), Why is the Market Share of Adjustable-Rate Mortgages so Low? Current Issues in Economics and Finance, Vol. 16(8).
Mackowiak, B., E. Moench and M. Wiederholt (2009), Sectoral Price Data and Models of Price Setting, Journal of Monetary Economics, Vol. 56, pp. S78-S99.
Moench, E. (2008), Forecasting the Yield Curve in a Data-Rich Environment: A No-Arbitrage Factor-Augmented VAR Approach, Journal of Econometrics, Vol. 146(1), pp. 26-43.
Moench, E. and H. Uhlig (2005), Towards a Monthly Business Cycle Chronology for the Euro Area, Journal of Business Cycle Measurement and Analysis, Vol. 2(1), pp. 43-69.
Working Papers
Crump, Richard K., S. Eusepi, and E. Moench (2018), The Term Structure of Expectations and Bond Yields, Federal Reserve Bank of New York Staff Reports No. 775, April 2018.
www.newyorkfed.org
Carvalho, Carlos, S. Eusepi, E. Moench, and B. Preston (2017): Anchored Inflation Expectations. (available at SSRN).
papers.ssrn.com
Adrian, Tobias, E. Moench and H. S. Shin (2016), Dynamic Leverage Asset Pricing, CEPR Discussion Paper No. DP11466, August 2016.
cepr.org
Adrian, Tobias, E. Moench and H.S. Shin (2010), Financial Intermediation, Asset Prices, and Macroeconomic Dynamics, Federal Reserve Bank of New York Staff Reports No. 422, September 2010.
www.newyorkfed.org
Awards
Amundi Smith Breeden First Prize, Journal of Finance, 2015
Young Economist Award, European Economic Association, 2008
Research Brief
The impact of Eurosystem bond purchases on the repo market
Research Brief | 21st edition – September 2018
28.09.2018 | Stephan Jank, Emanuel Mönch
Other Publications
VoxEU, Liberty Street Economics Blog
Lucca, D. and E. Moench (November 2018), "The Pre-FOMC Announcement Drift: More Recent Evidence"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Andrade, P., R. K. Crump, S. Eusepi and E. Moench (December 2014), "Learning from disagreement: Evidence from forecasters"
www.voxeu.org
Crump, R. K., S. Eusepi, D. Lucca, and E. Moench (December 2014), "Data Insight: Which Growth Rate? It's a Weighty Subject"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
O'Boyle, W., R. K. Crump, E. Moench, M. Raskin, C. Rosa and L. Stowe (December 2014), "Interest Rate Derivatives and Monetary Policy Expectations"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
O'Boyle, W., R. K. Crump, E. Moench, M. Raskin, C. Rosa and L. Stowe (December 2014), "Survey Measures of Expectations for the Policy Rate"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Crump, R. K., T. Davig, S. Eusepi and E. Moench (September 2014), "Connecting the Dots: Disagreement in the Federal Open Market Committee"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Adrian, T., R. K. Crump, B. Mills and E. Moench (May 2014), "Treasury Term Premia: 1961-Present"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Crump, R. K., S. Eusepi, and E. Moench (September 2013), "Preparing for Takeoff? Professional Fore-casters and the June 2013 FOMC Meeting"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Adrian, T., R. K. Crump, and E. Moench (April 2013), "Do Treasury Term Premia Rise around Monetary Tightenings?"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Crump, R., S. Eusepi, and E. Moench (January 2013), "Making a Statement: How Did Professional Fore-casters React to the August 2011 FOMC Statement?"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Lucca, D. and E. Moench (July 2012), "The Puzzling Pre-FOMC Announcement 'Drift' "
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Carvalho, C., N. Klagge, and E. Moench (October 2011), "How Well Do Financial Markets Separate News from Noise? Evidence from an Internet Blooper"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
Crump, R. K., S. Eusepi and E. Moench (August 2011), "A Look at the Accuracy of Policy Expectations"
libertystreeteconomics.newyorkfed.org
```

To write the prints in a txt file, the code is the following:

```
task=open("C:\Deutsche Bundesbank\Web_page_Bundesbank.txt", "a")
task.write(str(Researcher) + "\n")
task.close()
```

However, the result in the txt file is the following:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="52f7ac63-cd49-4643-b73a-952960dc4996", element="8a15ed96-ec84-49c3-a9c8-4774db8ca86e")>
```

What would be the proper way to write the prints in the txt file? Any advice or recommendation will be helpful

Many thanks,
Iván

Answer (score 2):

Your code is casting Researcher to string rather than getting its text as you do in your prints. Since the item does not override the default `__str__` method, Python just tells you what it can about the Researcher, which is the `WebElement` instance you see.

Instead of doing that, you should modify your code to write exactly the same thing you're printing.

```py
with open("C:\Deutsche Bundesbank\Web_page_Bundesbank.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(Researcher.text + "\n")
```

I've also changed your file opening to a more Pythonic way, the `with` operator will handle closing the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the following case you are writing the string representation of the Researcher object to your file.

```
task.write(str(Researcher) + "\n")
```

To write the prints to your file you can adjust your code just a litte:

```
task=open("C:\Deutsche Bundesbank\Web_page_Bundesbank.txt", "a")
task.write(Researcher.text + "\n")
task.close()
```

However I would suggest to use the with statement for writing to files because it handles the closing of a file automatically when the end of the with-block is reached:

```
with open("C:\Deutsche Bundesbank\Web_page_Bundesbank.txt", "a") as task:
    task.write(Researcher.text + "\n")
```